# Custom Circular Progress Bar with solid circles

Tags: android, progress-bar

i want to have one circular progress bar like this

[image]

I tried this but it not look like circular and how to put animation along with fades , because currently i am  using same xml for all six circles.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_shape_big_custom_search" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_shape_big_custom_search" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_shape_big_custom_search" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_shape_big_custom_search" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_shape_big_custom_search" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_shape_big_custom_search" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Check out : https://github.com/Fichardu/CircleProgress

Comment: Still this thread is open. Can any body help me to sort out this issue. ??

Answer (score 3):

Define progress bar like beloew code snip :

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/my_progress_indeterminate"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </ProgressBar>
```

**my_progress_indeterminate.xml [Place this file in drawable]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/image_for_rotation"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" />
```

**Place this Image file attched here in drawale :**
[image_to_be_place_in_drawable](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/image.axd?picture=2010%2F3%2FSteelBlue.png)

Comment: No doubt your ans really help full but i don't want to rotate, i want fades motion. Means every circular image will be own position but it should fades and shine in serialize way.

Comment: ok , it the above procedure almost images what u say i think it does not seems to be roatating when u keep the roation slow.

Comment: Yes... Image should be static but fades should happen in such a way it look like motion.

Comment: @BlueGreen make a custom **Drawable** class then and use a `TimeAnimator` to fade your circles

Comment: Is it possible by using alpha()?, i tried but not getting how to implement it successfully.

Comment: @BlueGreen yes: Paint#setAlpha()

Comment: @pskink.. for  TimeAnimator i followed this link http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=1555 but i am new for animation stuff, so can you help me with some code.?